# Identical SSH configuration failing

Tags: ssh, windows, sshd

I have 2 windows computers with an identical setup in putty. Same keys, logging into the same user accounts using the same proxy command.
These 2 computers connect to my linux network.
My linux network uses a bastion server.

If I connect directly to the bastion server everything works fine.
If I try to proxy to the main server things stop working.
I had this problem 2 weeks ago. Made no changes and it started working.
It has been working for 2 weeks. Now today, it has randomly stopped working again

I use this plink line in the Putty > Proxy > Telnet command

```
plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -i "C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\bastion.ppk" -agent -nc %host:%port
```

On the bastion server I can see both systems have identical logs up to a point

Non working:

```
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: debug3: receive packet: type 1 [preauth]
Feb 12 16:06:39 bastionserver sshd[6554]: error: Received disconnect from <client_ip> port 49763:14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

Working:

```
Feb 12 16:06:58 bastionserver sshd[6556]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Feb 12 16:06:58 bastionserver sshd[6556]: debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
Feb 12 16:06:58 bastionserver sshd[6556]: debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
Feb 12 16:06:58 bastionserver sshd[6556]: debug1: userauth-request for user screenreader service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
Feb 12 16:06:58 bastionserver sshd[6556]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Feb 12 16:06:58 bastionserver sshd[6556]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
Feb 12 16:06:58 bastionserver sshd[6556]: debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for RSA <SHA256> [preauth]
...
```

Comment: Do you have any encrypted filesystems on the Linux server? ... If so, is the user's `/home` directory encrypted? ... If the user's `/home` directory is encrypted, the connection will fail because the public key is unreadable inside the user's `/home/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: 1) Linux server is not encrypted
2) If encryption was the problem neither of my windows servers would be able to connect but 1 is able to connect every time

Comment: So, two Windows machines... one always works and one always doesn't work?  One always works and one sometimes works?  The same machine always works? Or sometimes the working machine switches? ... Does the first machine to attempt login always work? ... It's not clear from your question...

Comment: Machine 1 always works
|
Machine 2 worked for a period of time, now does not work

Answer (score 0):

This problem reappeared after the server restarted.
It isn't clear to me what changed but after the restart the SSH key used in the plink command wasn't being read any more.

This was diagnosed by clicking `Yes` under `Print proxy diagnostics in the terminal window` on PuTTy's proxy page

In the path I listed above,  was actually very important.
The user name begins with \r

So instead of attempting to run:
`plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -i "C:\Users\rick\.ssh\bastion.ppk" -agent -nc %host:%port`

It was actually trying to running:
`plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -i "C:\Usersick\.ssh\bastion.ppk" -agent -nc %host:%port`

Comment: Doesn't Windows cope with `/` as path separators nowadays?